# Swift: reflection thanks to infoDictionary

Tags: unit-testing, reflection, swift3, resourcedictionary

I try to instanciate a new class from a string class name, like we can easy do in Java. I have finally wrote this function:

```
func stringClassFromString(_ className: String) -> AnyClass! {
    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
    let cls: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className)")!;
    return cls;
}
```

Thanks to some googling, but as soon as I tried this solution thanks to a unit test :

```
func test() {
    let myclass = stringClassFromString("NSDate") as! NSDate.Type
    let instance = myclass.init()
    print(instance)
}
```

I have an exception (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)) as soon as my test use the line : let namespace... I tried to see the content of the infoDictionary, he's empty. So my question is simple, is it because of the unit tests context that my dictionary is empty ? Is there any method or library (like robolectric for android) to simulate an infoDicionary for testing purpose.

Comment: Why would you want to instantiate a class from a String classname? One of the biggest advantages of Swift is its static type checker, which you completely skip when you try to do stuff like creating classes from dynamic identifiers. Moreover, try to use native Swift classes when available instead of the Foundation ones (such as `Date` instead of `NSDate`).

Comment: I'm learning Swift development and reflection I think can be an interesting to learn. Thanks for your advice I do avoid to use Foundation classes but here it was just an example.

Comment: If you are in the early stages of learning Swift, don't bother with reflection. Learn the basics of the type system first and later on if you find a problem that you really cannot solve while fully utilising the static type checker, then have a look again at reflections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed to find my error, instead of using the main Bundle, I use the constructor of the Bundle class to build a Bundle which will correspond to the current context :

```
let namespace = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
```

And tadda, it's working !